# Trouble with looping over an unknown depth object

Tags: javascript

I'm working on comment threading with sorting by votes.  I have a base object that looks like this.

```
{
"user_name": "string",
"comment": "string",
"points": "integer",
"date_time": "dateObject",
"avatar_pic": "URL",
"profile_link": "URL"
}
```

You can ignore the fact everything is a string for now.  Just doing that for testing.

Here is the larger object with multiple comments. There will be an unknown nesting depth.

```
{
"comments": [
    {
        "user_name": "string",
        "comment": "string",
        "points": "integer",
        "date_time": "dateObject",
        "child": [
            {
                "user_name": "string",
                "comment": "string",
                "points": "integer",
                "date_time": "dateObject",
                "child" : null,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user_name": "string",
        "comment": "string",
        "points": "integer",
        "date_time": "dateObject",
        "child": null
    }
]
```

}

My working theory in psudo code right now goes something like this.

```
for each iteration of loop over comments array call someFunction

someFunction(){
for by points
write properties of object to screen
check if child property has an array.  If array call someFunction on that array.
}
```

Basically the for loops would automatically check for nesting.  Then if its there loop further down and keep building the comments in a logical order on screen. The only other requirement I'm trying to keep in mind is nesting depth.  I would like to indent the comments based on their nesting level.  To a max of 3 or 4 indents, then they would just go straight down instead of indenting further on the page.

The larger format is completely flexible.  If there is a better data structure to use I'm all for it.  I hope this makes sense and you guys rock!!

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the indentation, or about the recursive function call? Seems like you pretty much know what to do, so I'm not clear on what you're asking about.

Comment: Yhea I think its tracking the indentation and recursive function call I'm struggling with.

Comment: The indentation can be tracked simply by passing a number as an argument. You can use a multiple of that number to create a string for indentation. When a recursive call is made, an incremented value of the number is passed along. You can cap it at whatever maximum you want. I think you've got a handle on how the recursive function works otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function process (obj, func) {
    func(obj);
    if (obj.child) {
        obj.child.forEach(function (child) {
            process(child, func);
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
process(yourObj, function (obj) {
    // e.g.
    cosnole.log(obj.user_name);
});
```

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks, not sure why I was having trouble with this one.  I knew I was close :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right what you're trying to do, you pseudo code would look like this :

```
someFunction(){
if child property has an array -> call someFunction()  

else child property has null -> process, and then set this very child to null, and call someFunction again
}
```

For a better oversee of those kinds of object traversal, you should look at [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) and a peculiar way to traverse them, [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), which is quite close for what I ma understanding you want to do

Comment: @Call_Back_Function yes indeed, if you appreciated, you can upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

IMO the structure is good if you need to have nested comments. If you don't, having it won't eat too much resources. I suggest to save each comment depth when printing it to html, then you can style it as you want.